# UICollectionView showing wrong cells after scrolling - dequeue issue?

Tags: pdf, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView within a UIViewController. In the collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath: method, it creates a series of custom cells based on the datasource. The custom cells in turn contain a UIView, subclassed to draw single PDF pages.

It's set up in such a way as to split a PDF file into its single pages, so cell 1 contains PDF page 1, cell 2 contains PDF page 2 and so on. So far so good, here's my problem:

When I scroll down, the UICollectionView starts displaying the wrong cells. For instance in a 34 page document, it shows cells/pages 1-16 in the correct order, but then starts displaying pages that *seemed* to have been dequeued further up, such as cell 1, cell 2, cell 4. I never get anywhere near cell/page 34.

I've seen similar behaviour from UITableView in the past, and believe it has something to do with the dequeueing of the cells, or a delegate method. Not quite sure - any help is appreciated.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//create custom cell
CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//set file name (always the same; one PDF file)
cell.fileName = fileName;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

//set the title to the page number
cell.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page %@", [countArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

//set the current page (which indicates which page to display) according to the pageCount
cell.currentPage = [[countArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];

return cell; }
```

Comment: Maybe I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've had similare issues. This is most likely because the reused cells do not redraw themselves. In your custom cell's **content** class (your PDF view), trigger redrawing if the frame is updated:

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [super setFrame:frame];
    [self setNeedsDisplay]; // force drawRect:
}
```

This worked for me. In addition, if your cell size may change, set the autoresizing mask so that it fills space with

```
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

during initialization.

Comment: This worked for me - thank you for your help. Calling the setFrame method above from inside the cellForItemAtIndexPath of the UICollectionView, forced the PDFs to redraw. Many thanks.

Comment: Great! Calling `setFrame:` yourself is probably not necessary because the collection view does this anyway.

Comment: setting the resizing mask helped,

Comment: I followed Chris's suggestion, though I actually needed to call `setNeedsDisplay` on the cell after I set it up and before returning it.

Answer (score 13):

Fixed similar issue using prepareForReuse method

just add this method to your custom cell implementation

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {

     self.fileName = nil;
     self.title = nil;

     // add remaining properties 

}
```

Comment: @PuneethKamath you don't need to call this method, just add this in you UICollectionViewCell subclass

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar issue in swift based on Asatur Galstyan's answer.

After associating a custom class to a cell in a storyboard the prepareForReuse() function can be overriden:

```
import UIKit

class SomeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var exampleView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var exampleLabel: UILabel!

    override func prepareForReuse(){
        super.prepareForReuse()
        exampleLabel.textColor = nil
        exampleView.backgroundColor = nil
        exampleView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    }
}
```

There default implementation of prepareForReuse() does nothing (at least in iOS 10) but [Apple recommends calling the the super.prepareForReuse() when overriding anyway](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse).

Comment: Working from your example, I've found that `exampleView.setNeedsDisplay()` within `prepareForReuse()` solved the problem.