# UICollectionView shows wrong cell selected issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `CollectionView` with many cell's. Once I select one of them all shows the same name but when I scroll I get again all cell with different name but all are the same. So each scroll give me different name but all has the same name. So please where could be my issue?

I've checked this [UICollectionView showing wrong cells after scrolling - dequeue issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163834/uicollectionview-showing-wrong-cells-after-scrolling-dequeue-issue) but it didn't help me.

BTW in the same I have a `tableView` and it is working fine.

Update question:
HOW I CAN CALL THE SELECTED CELL LABEL OUT SIDE THE `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` FOR `UICollectionView`?

Solution:

```
NSIndexPath *path2 = [[_collection indexPathsForSelectedItems] lastObject];
ProductsCollectionViewCell *cell2 = (ProductsCollectionViewCell *) [_collection cellForItemAtIndexPath:path2];
```

THIS IS HOW I DID IT.

///////////////////////////////////////////////

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

self.lblCollectionId = nil;
self.lblCollection = nil;

static NSString *identifier = @"cell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

_lblCollection = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
_lblCollection.text = [_arraySubCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

_lblCollectionId = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
_lblCollectionId.text = [_arrayID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

_imgCollection = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];

[_imgCollection sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[_arrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [_tbl indexPathForSelectedRow];
    ProductsTableViewCell *cell = (ProductsTableViewCell *) [_tbl cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    _selectedID = cell.lblID.text;

    _selectedIDCollection = _lblCollectionId.text;
    NSLong(@"%@ Selected", _selectedIDCollection);
}
```

UPDATED for Ias:

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"proCell";
ProductsCollectionViewCell *proCell = [_collection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

proCell.lblProduct.text = [_arraySubCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
proCell.lblID.text = [_arrayID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tags is a very bad idea, especially here beacause you defined you tags on the prototype cell so it's the same for each cell.
You must create a custom collectionViewCell class and link the labels and imageView with IBOutlet so you can access these normally :

```
CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.label1.text = [_arraySubCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.label2.text = [_arrayID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Check [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial), it explains step by step how you should do it.

Comment: Now I have did what you said but I'm getting the selected cell `null`. How I can show that?

Comment: Did you add a prototype cell in your tableView with an identifier corresponding with the identifier your are passing in the dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier method ?

Comment: If you can tell me the way call the `lblProduct` for collection it may work. I can call as index for UITableView but couldn't know how in UICollectionView.

Comment: Check the steps 4 and 5 of the tutorial i have posted in my edited response, after that dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier will not return nil.

Comment: I can't see the way how to print the selected label cell.  Please can you help me with that?

Comment: It is started to work after adding my work with yours. Thanks.